# LISP function to return the greater number

Tags: function, parameters, lisp, common-lisp

I feel like an idiot asking for help for this, but I have been stuck for hours now, and I haven't been able to find anything on the internet that can help me.

I am trying to write a function in LISP that takes in two parameters and returns the number that is greater. Here's what I have at the moment, but I keep getting errors:

```
(defun greater (x y)
  (if (> x y) x y))
```

I am calling it like this:

```
(greater (2 1))
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Common Lisp expert, but I guess the way you are calling `greater` is wrong. This program works for me:

```
(defun greater (x y) (if (> x y) x y))

(print (greater 5 12))
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Yeah, I've been calling it wrong. I think the way I've been calling it was making the program interpret is a list. Thanks for the help!